# How to get Baseline of TextView with given font and font size? Please see my case

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fonts

I am setting custom trur type font of my TextView and set text size; then using setText() method i set text to the TextView. It shows perfect text. But when i try to get baseline of this TextView it shows 1 or -1. Why is it??

I am doing like this;

```
TextView tv;
tv.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"customFont.ttf"));
tv.setTextSize(20);
tv.setText("My name is Tahir");

tv.getBaseline(); 
//this returns -1. (if i set Height and width of tv suppose 100 the getBaseline() retruns 1)
tv.getTop();
tv.getBottom();
```

Please help me what may be the problem???

Comment: Answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38524921/5455629

Answer (score 0):

Have you declare `android:baselineAligned` in your Linear or Relative layout whatever you used
in your xml.

for example :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="true" >

    <TextView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/hello"
        android:id="@+id/text1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Yes sir I have already done it as android:baselineAligned="true". if i android:layout_width="100dp" and android:layout_height="100dp" then tv.getBaseLine() returns 1. Please state that what else i should consider?

Answer (score 0):

Try obtaining the baseline after layout and rendering has already happened. That is definitely after onCreate(...), for instance.