# getBaseline of TextView returns -1

Tags: android-layout, textview, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, baseline

I am trying to align two `TextView` one is inside `HorizontalScrollView`, and both are children of `LinerLayout` .

When I am trying to call `getBaseLine` of `TextView` inside `onWindowAttached` of RecyclerView Adapter it always returns -1.

Yes, the parent view of `TextView`, `LinerLayout` has `android:baselineAligned="true"`

---

Edit : Adding Code

Layout

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="6dp"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:baselineAligned="true"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/outerTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"


                android:gravity="center_vertical" />

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scrollView"

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/inlineTextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"

                    />
            </HorizontalScrollView>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Code in RecyclerView Adapter

```
@Override
public void onViewAttachedToWindow(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder)
{
    super.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder);
    if(holder instanceof MyHolder)
    {
        dostuff((MyHolder)holder);
    }
}
private void dostuff(QACommentViewHolder holder)
{
    int baseline  = holder.outerTextView.getBaseline();

}
```

Comment: @Sharj Please see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

`View` is not measured when `onViewAttachedToWindow` is called, hence it is returning -1.

Better approach would be.

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        .
        .
        .
        viewHolder.itemView.post(new Runnable()
                {

                   //put your code here
```